# I've already defined axes. But the error says that it is not defined

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

```
def plotPrediction(b,x,y,predfcn):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    axes.scatter(x, y)
    xp = np.linspace(min(x),max(x),num=50)
    yp = predfcn(b,xp)
    axes.plot(xp,yp,'r')


sns.scatterplot(x = 'age', y = 'tailL', data = df, ax=axes)
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Tail Length')
x_simulated = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), num = len(x))
y_pred1 = simpleRegPredict(b, x_simulated)
xp = np.linspace(min(x),max(x),num=50)
yp = simpleRegPredict(b,xp)
axes.plot(xp,yp,'r')
```

I'm trying to display the scatterplot for the data, and it shows an error that the axes are not defined.

Comment: `axes` and `fig` are local variables within that function.  When the function returns, those go away.  Perhaps you should create the `subplots` outside the function and pass in `axes`.

Comment: It looks like you're using the python library matplotlib, but not MATLAB - is that correct? If so, the MATLAB tag should be changed to matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

When you define the name `axes` to point to your new `matplotlib` axes object, it is only defined within the scope of the `plotPrediction` function. In the outer (presumably global) scope, that name has *not* been defined, and attempting to access it there will result in a `NameError`.

Each "scope" is essentially a dictionary of names that have been defined in a particular context, and when you access a name, it searches through the local scope, then any enclosing scopes that exist. Since the local `plotPrediction` scope does not enclose the global scope, variables defined within `plotPrediction` are considered undefined in the global scope.

[Here's a pretty good intro to what scope means and how it works in python](https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/) - I recommend you give it a read.

The solution depends on how you want to organize your code - it's not clear to me what the best option is, because I don't exactly understand what the context is, and we only have a piece of your code.

You could bring all the code into the `plotPrediction` function, like this:

```
def plotPrediction(b,x,y,predfcn):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    axes.scatter(x, y)
    xp = np.linspace(min(x),max(x),num=50)
    yp = predfcn(b,xp)
    axes.plot(xp,yp,'r')


    sns.scatterplot(x = 'age', y = 'tailL', data = df, ax=axes)
    plt.xlabel('Age')
    plt.ylabel('Tail Length')
    x_simulated = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), num = len(x))
    y_pred1 = simpleRegPredict(b, x_simulated)
    xp = np.linspace(min(x),max(x),num=50)
    yp = simpleRegPredict(b,xp)
    axes.plot(xp,yp,'r')
```

Or you could return the value referenced by `axes` from the function - then you can use it in the global scope:

```
def plotPrediction(b,x,y,predfcn):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    axes.scatter(x, y)
    xp = np.linspace(min(x),max(x),num=50)
    yp = predfcn(b,xp)
    axes.plot(xp,yp,'r')
    # Here we're passing the axes value out to the calling scope
    return axes

# This line defines axes in the global scope, so it can be used there
axes = plotPrediction(b,x,y,predfcn)

sns.scatterplot(x = 'age', y = 'tailL', data = df, ax=axes)
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Tail Length')
x_simulated = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), num = len(x))
y_pred1 = simpleRegPredict(b, x_simulated)
xp = np.linspace(min(x),max(x),num=50)
yp = simpleRegPredict(b,xp)
axes.plot(xp,yp,'r')
```

You'll have to decide which makes more sense given your context and goals.